# How to enable middle touchpad button in VMware which has Fedora/Mate as a guest?

Tags: fedora, vmware, touchpad, mate-desktop

My company laptop has been replaced. I moved from Precision 7730 (which had 3 physical touchpad buttons) to Precision 7680 which doesn't have any touchpad button, and I really miss them.

My host is Windows 10 x64 22H2. In the touchpad settings I assigned to "Three-finger gestures" the "Middle mouse button". This works fine.

However, I'm running Fedora with MATE under VMware Player. And here, the trick doesn't work. I'd like to have the middle touchpad button here as well. But don't know if this is something to be investigated in VMware, or in Fedora, or in MATE.

The best would be the middle button is clicked when I touch the touchpad with 3 fingers at the same time like I have it under Windows.

Is there a way?

Comment: I don't think you're looking at the right places: your linux itself doesn't handle the touchpad driver; it gets a virtual pointing device. So, you need to figure out how to tell VMWare Player to pass through the same middle mouse button events as you have in the rest of windows.